# Truffle test is failing with "the tx doesn't have the correct nonce" error

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm building the decentralized exchange app and currently covering my main contract with tests.
I've created several mocked tokens that are used during the test process (here is an example of one of them):

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Dai is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Dai Stablecoin", "DAI") {}

    function faucet(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do? I'm trying to mint tokens before each test execution.

Here is my test:

```js
const expectRevert = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers/src/expectRevert');

const Dai = artifacts.require('mocks/Dai.sol');
const Bat = artifacts.require('mocks/Bat.sol');
const Rep = artifacts.require('mocks/Rep.sol');
const Zrx = artifacts.require('mocks/Zrx.sol');
const Dex = artifacts.require('Dex.sol');

contract('Dex', (accounts) => {
  let tokenList;
  let dai, bat, rep, zrx, dex;

  const [trader1, trader2] = [accounts[1], accounts[2]];
  const [DAI, BAT, REP, ZRX] = ['DAI', 'BAT', 'REP', 'ZRX'].map((ticker) =>
    web3.utils.fromAscii(ticker)
  );

  beforeEach(async () => {
    tokenList = await Promise.all([Dai.new(), Bat.new(), Rep.new(), Zrx.new()]);
    [dai, bat, rep, zrx] = tokenList;

    dex = await Dex.new();

    await Promise.all([
      dex.addToken(DAI, dai.address),
      dex.addToken(BAT, bat.address),
      dex.addToken(REP, rep.address),
      dex.addToken(ZRX, zrx.address),
    ]);

    const amount = web3.utils.toWei('1000');
    const seedTokenBalance = async (token, trader) => {
      await token.faucet(trader, amount);
      await token.approve(dex.address, amount, {
        from: trader,
      });
    };

    await Promise.all(
      tokenList.map((token) => seedTokenBalance(token, trader1))
    );
    await Promise.all(
      tokenList.map((token) => seedTokenBalance(token, trader2))
    );
  });

  describe('deposit', () => {
    it('should deposit token', async () => {
      const amount = web3.utils.toWei('100');

      await dex.deposit(amount, DAI, {
        from: trader1,
      });

      const balance = await dex.traderBalances(trader1, DAI);

      assert(balance.toString() === amount);
    });

    it('should NOT deposit tokens if token does not exist', async () => {
      await expectRevert(
        dex.deposit(
          web3.utils.toWei('100'),
          web3.utils.fromAscii('TOKEN-DOES-NOT-EXIST'),
          { from: trader1 }
        ),
        'Token does not exist.'
      );
    });
  });
});
```

My test is constantly failing on that part of code:

```
await token.approve(dex.address, amount, {
        from: trader,
      });
```

with the following error:

> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 1 tx has nonce of: 0 (vm hf=london -> block -> tx) -- Reason given: Custom error (could not decode).

**How can I fix this nonce inconsistency? Can anybody explain me the meaning of this error?**

Here is my truffle-config.js file:

```js
// require('dotenv').config();
// const { MNEMONIC, PROJECT_ID } = process.env;

// const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters, etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.8.17', // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    },
  },

  
};
```

Comment: Can you try `truffle migrate --reset`

Comment: @Yilmaz, yes I've tried - no result

Comment: instead of `beforeEach` can you write `before`